# How to get thumbnail images in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpthumb, php-gd

I have larger images stored in one folder. I dont want to create thumbnail images, store it some place and retrieve. I am looking for script to create thumbnail images of larger images dynamically and display in the browser but never storing the thumbnail image on the server.
Could someone recommend me some links to tutorial or provide me script to do so? I have found phpthumb() http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ doing such work in php. How could I use it zend framework or other library, please recommend

Edit : How to use phpthumb() http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ ?
phpthumb() has a bunch of class files. To generate thumbnail in phpthumb() we only require to write the following line:

```
<img src="phpthumb.php?src=image.jpg&w=150"/>
```

I want to use it in zend framework. Where should I place this library? Placing inside the library folder, I would have to rename all the classes and its references. How to do use it? any other techniques

Comment: To use with Zend Framework v1 or v2, you can place the library anywhere you want, and then add the location to your `include_path`. You don't need to rename any of the classes. For performance, you should set up a `cache` folder, as phpThumb's readme.txt says: "thumbnailing is slow and processor-intensive. Enabling caching will dramatically speed up future thumbnail serving"

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to provide HTTP access to your source images, you could use a free service like [TinySrc](http://www.sencha.com/products/io/), to provide thumbnails. Neither Zend Framework v1, or Zend Framework v2, provides support for image manipulation that I can see.

Comment: thanks for your reply but as far i understood, tinysrc is resizing tool for mobile devices. Could you please take a loot at http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ Its very good at what it does

Comment: According to http://docs.sencha.io/0.3.3/index.html#!/guide/src you can define the size of your images, so I don't know why you couldn't use it for any device.